# Google App Engine communicate with Compute Engine over internal network

Tags: google-app-engine, tcp, google-compute-engine

We're building an application in the google cloud. We're using App Engine as frontend and Compute Engine as backend. On these Compute Engine instances I'm running a TCP server that accepts certain "command" messages. The Compute Engine instances are also connected to the internet behind a firewall and load balancer for incoming https traffic. I would like to bind the TCP server to a local IP addres and allow only App Engine instances (thes are within the same project) to connect to the TCP "commands" port via the [socket api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/).

For now we're limiting the incoming connections to [Google Ip's only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534135/compute-engine-firewall-for-app-engine-url-fetch)

The [Compute Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#networks) sais the following:

> Every instance is a member of a single network. A network performs the same function that a router does in a home network: it describes the network range and gateway IP address, handles communication between instances, and serves as a gateway between instances and callers outside the network. A network is constrained to a single project; it cannot span projects. Any communication between instances in different networks, even within the same project, must be through external IP addresses. In the API, a network is represented by the Network object.

Would it be possible to build a secure communication setup? Perhaps with App Engine backend instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to setup a private network between GCE and GAE. Limiting to google's IP range isn't secure since anyone on GAE or GCE could connect to your server.  So I recommend that you authenticate incoming connections at your TCP server to verify the connection is coming from your GAE instances.

Comment: I was planning on adding that indeed. I'm also looking for network layer security. Not just application. But I think you're right, right now that is the only thing I can do.

Comment: Is this something I can do as soon as I have access to managed VM's? Since as far as I understand it AE and my compute engine app are located on the same machine. Am I now able to talk over localhost?

Comment: is this answer still valid for today? '__')? i'm planning to use GAE and CGE (aerospike)

Comment: we recently switched from App Engine to Tornado for both speed and this reason.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate with the newly released VPC connector.

Comment: @SjuulJanssen What is Tornado?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ It's an asynchronous webserver in python. Since then we've moved away from tornado as well to asyncio and aiohttp

Answer (score 7):

With App Engine Flexible, you can setup instance_tags and use that to create firewall rules with the appropriate tagging rules. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml for more information.

Comment: I added instance_tag for App Engine Flexible app. And I added a firewall rule. The source tag is the instance_tag and I set the target tag for a GCE instance. However I can't access the GCE instance. Are there any process I missed? The GCE instance is under an internal load balancer.

Comment: You are no longer limited to the flexible environment with the new VPC connector functionality.

Answer (score 4):

As of now In 2016 as google cloud has launched google cloud flexible environment [appengine/docs/flexible/](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/). So yes it is possible now because now both app engine and compute engine are present in same network and therefore using app engine you can access compute engine by using their internal Ip, also remember to delete all external firewall rules for your compute engines if you only want to allow access from app engine.

Comment: The VPC connector is now the correct approach without limitation to which environment you are running in.

Answer (score 1):

As of [April 9, 2019](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/release-notes#april_9_2019), you can use the [serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/connecting-vpc) to allow your App Engine application to connect to other services on the Google Cloud Platform. I linked to the Python standard environment docs, but this applies to any language on App Engine in either runtime environment.

Comment: Can this be used for Google Apps Script projects?