# Proxy outbound API calls from Google App Engine via Google Compute Engine running Squid

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, vpc

I'm trying to proxy outbound API calls made from a Google App Engine application via a Google Compute Engine server VM instance running Squid proxy server.

The aim is that the REST api calls will all be made from a static ip address so that the 3rd party API will be able to identify and permit the calls via their firewall.

I have read and followed the instructions on this post:

[connect Google App Engine and Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308749/connect-google-app-engine-and-google-compute-engine/57571915#57571915)

I have managed to do the following so far:

1. Created a Google cloud compute VM and successfully assigned it a static external IP address.
2. Created a Serverless VPC access connector successfully (all resources are located in the same GAE region).
3. Added the vpc_access_connector name to my app.yaml in the Google App Engine project (which runs on Node.js).
4. Deployed the app using gcloud beta, with api calls being targeted towards the internal IP address of the proxy server, using the correct Squid default port (3128).
5. On issuing a request from the GAE app, I can see from the server logs that the correct IP address and port are being attempted but get the following error: "Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED [my-internal-ip-address]:3128"

I've also tried running a curl command from the cloud shell interface, but the request times out every time.

If anyone could help solve this issue, I will be very grateful.

Comment: What is the App Engine environment? Standard or Flexible? I would recommend you to follow the relevant section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/connecting-vpc), which uses `gcloud app deploy` instead of `gcloud beta app deploy`.

Comment: @DanielOcando sorry, but I've read that a great many times and followed the instructions precisely. Prior to deploying with gcloud beta, I deployed with gcloud and it made no difference. I've now created a new vpc connector, redeployed using gcloud (not beta) and created a new compute engine VM to see if I can get a response at all using the new vpc connector. I have checked the vpc firewall rules and made sure that the port is open to ingress traffic. If I curl from App Engine to the internal ip address of the compute engine vm (+ port), it just times out.

Comment: @DanielOcando - also, I'm using Standard environment.

Comment: I can see two possible causes for the "ECONNREFUSED":1. A misconfiguration of the [SQUID server inside the Compute Engine Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#proxyvm). SSH into the VM and run `sudo sed -i 's:#\(acl localnet src [SERVERLESS_VPC_ACCESS_CONNECTOR_IP]/28.*\):\1:' /etc/squid/squid.conf` to add your Serveless VPC Access connector to the [Squid's server ACL](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#ACL_elements) and then [restart the server](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-squid-proxy-server-ubuntu-16-04/) for the changes to take effect.

Comment: 2. A misconfiguration of the VPC network. Did you add the firewall rule to allow traffic on port 3128? If you are using the [default network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#default-network), the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create) should work: `gcloud compute firewall-rules create NAME --network default --allow tcp:3128` (change NAME to the name you want for the Firewall Rule).

Comment: @DanielOcando Thanks for these - I've checked both thoroughly, and unfortunately they haven't solved the issue. To expand, I've SSH'd into the Squid VM and checked that the IP address of the VPC connector is listed in the acl list, and it is there correctly. Just to double-check, I used your command and then restarted the server. I've also checked the VPC network firewall rules, and there is a rule in there allowing tcp:3128 ingress for squid which is on the correct default network. I'm then SSH'ing into the app engine instance and running curl xx.xxx.x.x:3128 --verbose from the command line.

Comment: @DanielOcando The result is the same: Failed to connect to xx.xxx.x.x port 3128: Connection timed out

Comment: If there are no issues with your VPC or SQUID configuration, I guess the issue should rely on your App Engine application. If you are using the [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) dependency to issue the requests. Make sure to add the [HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables](https://github.com/request/request#controlling-proxy-behaviour-using-environment-variables) pointing to your Compute Engine instance's internal IP Address in a similar fashion to `HTTP_PROXY: "http://[INTERNAL-IP-GCE]:3128"` and `HTTPS_PROXY: "http://[INTERNAL-IP-GCE]:3128"`

Comment: Find the information on how to add the environment variables to your app.yaml [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207283/discussion-between-jonhendrix-and-daniel-ocando).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible example of how to proxy outbound HTTP requests from an App Engine Standard application on NodeJS runtime via a Compute Engine VM running Squid, based on a slight modification of the available Google Cloud Platform documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#proxyvm) [2](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) and Quickstarts [3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart).

**1. Create a Serverless VPC Access conector**: Basically follow [2](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) to create the connector. After updating the `gcloud` components and enabling the Serverless VPC Access API on your project running the following command should suffice:

```
gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors create [CONNECTOR_NAME] \
--network [VPC_NETWORK] \
--region [REGION] \
--range [IP_RANGE]
```

**2. Create a Compute Engine VM to use as proxy**: Basically follow [1](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#proxyvm) to set up a Squid proxy server:

a. [Reserve a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static) and [assign it to a Compute Engine VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#assign_new_instance).

b. Add a [Firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) to allow traffic on Squid's default port: 3128. This command should work if you are using the [default VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#default-network): `gcloud compute firewall-rules create [FIREWALL_RULE_NAME] --network default --allow tcp:3128`

c. Install Squid on the VM with the following command `sudo apt-get install squid3`.

d. Enable the `acl localnet src` entries in the Squid config files for the VPC Access connector:

```
sudo sed -i 's:#\(http_access allow localnet\):\1:' /etc/squid/squid.conf
sudo sed -i 's:#\(acl localnet src [IP_RANGE]/28.*\):\1:' /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

For example: if you used 10.8.0.0 as value for the [IP_RANGE] field for creating the connector, it should look something like `sudo sed -i 's:#\(acl localnet src 10.8.0.0/28.*\):\1:' /etc/squid/squid.conf`

e. Start the server with `sudo service squid start`

**3. Modifications on App Engine application**: Based on the [Quickstart for Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart) modify the following files in order to create an application that [crawls a webpage using the request-promise library](https://github.com/request/request-promise#crawl-a-webpage) and displays the HTML of the webpage. The request is send to the webpage [using the VPC Access connector](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/connecting-vpc#configuring) and the VM as a proxy with the modifications of the app.yaml and app.js files.

a. package.json

```
...
    "test": "mocha --exit test/*.test.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^7.0.0",
...
```

b. app.js

```
'use strict';
// [START gae_node_request_example]
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .send('Hello, world!')
    .end();
});
//Add a handler to test the web crawler
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  var request = require('request-promise');
  request('http://www.input-your-awesome-website.com')
    .then(function (htmlString) {
      res.send(htmlString)
         .end();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      res.send("Crawling Failed...")
         .end();
    });
});
// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
// [END gae_node_request_example]
```

c. app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10
vpc_access_connector:
  name: "projects/[PROJECT]/locations/[REGION]/connectors/[CONNECTOR_NAME]"
env_variables:
  HTTP_PROXY: "http://[Compute-Engine-IP-Address]:3128"
  HTTPS_PROXY: "http://[Compute-Engine-IP-Address]:3128"
```

Each time you go to the `/test` handler monitor that the requests go through the proxy by using `sudo tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log` command from the VM and checking the changes on the logs.

**Notes**: The connector, application and VM need to be on the same region to work and [these are the supported regions for the connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#supported_regions).

Comment: I can find the logs when I do outbound request, but I am getting TCP_DENIED errors inside the logs. How can I debug where it is going wrong?

Comment: Where are you using the http_proxy and https_proxy env variables defined in app.yaml? Which compute engine ip address should be used? internal or external ip?

Comment: The env variables for the proxy are meant to be used at the OS system level in a similar fashion to [what's explained here](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/set-up-proxy-http-proxy-environment-variable/). You should use the internal IP as the route should be App Engine - VPC Connector - Internal IP - Squid - External IP.

Comment: But more importantly, these explanations are very outdated. As this is not a very scalable solution. If you want to assign a static IP address to App Engine please use a NEG, as it is the correct solution for this use case. All the information can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts).