# Connect Google App Engine to PostgreSQL database on GCE

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm new to Google Cloud. I have set up PostgreSQL on Google Compute Engine [[as per this tutorial]](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres#creating-a-compute-engine-instance) and I have deployed Node.js on Google App Engine [[following this guide]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs).

My **app.js** code is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const pg = require('pg');
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var config = 'postgresql://username:password@[VM Instance External IP]:5432/database'
var client = new pg.Client(config);

client.connect();

app.enable('trust proxy');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/index.html', {root: __dirname })
});

app.get('/look', (req, res) => {
    client.query(
        'SELECT * FROM users', function(err, result, fields){
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send(result);
        }
    );
});

app.listen(PORT,() => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I have set up the following Firewall rule:

```
NAME       NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW      IP RANGES   DENY  DISABLED
postgres   default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:5432   0.0.0.0/0         False
```

I have edited **postgresql.conf** to enable Postgres to listen on all IP addresses:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

and added the following line in **pg_hba.conf** file:

```
host    all             all           0.0.0.0/0          md5
```

When I run it on my machine, it connects successfully to Postgres. However, when I run it on Google App Engine, I get the following response code (meaning connection shut off in the middle of processing the request through the server):

```
499
```

I will really appreciate your help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine will never connect to your VM instance in this way, actually this issue is very common in SO (For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308749/connect-google-app-engine-and-google-compute-engine)).

To connect to your VM, you should create a [VPC Serverless Connector](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/connecting-vpc) which will allow you to access resources inside the VPC like in your case a VM or any others like Memorystore. You can follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/connecting-vpc) and then, in your code instead of using the public IP of the VM, you may want to use the private IP of the VM, i.e. :

```js
var config = 'postgresql://username:password@[VM Instance Internal IP]:5432/database'
```

If the other configurations are fine (Firewall, service running, etc), you will be able to connect to your database.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) for your DB instead? Having a managed database, rather than running one in a VM, will be a bit easier to maintain long term and will simplify connecting services in a secure way. There is even a tutorial on getting it setup!

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard