# How to establish a private connection between Google app engine and compute engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a web app/Api which is currently running on a google app engine resource. As the calculations of the API are very computing intensive, i have outsourced the computational part to a managed auto-scaling google compute engine group, with a HTTP load balancer in the front end (to maintain a single IP address and balance load accross the several engines that are dynamically spawning).

Currently, i just make an HTTP call to the load balancer IP address from the app engine. As the GAE and GCE are in the same region, this however feels highly innefficient (i am aware that the app engine and compute engines are still in two physically seperated data centers). This also poses a security threat as I am constently receiving calls from random IP bots trying to exploit potential security loopholes. Additionally, i am only verfying API token validity at the app engine level, as i do not want to give user database access to the compute engine (security reasons), so this means that there is no verification beeing done between app engine and compute engine, so that the latter answers all calls that it gets.

**Is there a way to establish a private connection between the app engine and cloud engine?**

My goal would be to not have to open the GCE to the whole internet, bearing in mind that it is only receiving calls from one IP adress/resource

I have tried whitelisting only the app engines IP addresses, but this unforthunately is a large block of adresses, is very cumbersome to retrieve and changes dynamically. The app engine also cannot use the private IP of the compute engine/ google SQL servers.

Other creative ideas are highly welcome!

Comment: Does the following add anything to the story ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155795/google-app-engine-communicate-with-compute-engine-over-internal-network

Comment: Another related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19155795/320399

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) may be a potential solution.  The following is taken from the overview:

> Serverless VPC Access enables you to connect from the App Engine
>   standard environment and Cloud Functions directly to your VPC network.
>   This connection makes it possible for your App Engine standard
>   environment apps and Cloud Functions to access resources in your VPC
>   network via internal (private) IP addresses. Using internal IP
>   addresses improves the latency of communication between your Google
>   Cloud Platform services and avoids exposing internal resources to the
>   public internet.
>
> Serverless VPC Access only allows your app or function to send
>   requests to resources in your VPC network and receive responses to
>   those requests. Communication in the opposite direction, where a VM
>   initiates a request to an app or function, requires you to use the
>   public address of the app or function.

Comment: Thank you! helped me out a lot!