# Cannot match region between Google App Engine & VPC Network

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-vpc

I am [setting a private connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56317017/how-to-establish-a-private-connection-between-google-app-engine-and-compute-engi) between my project's Google App Engine and Compute engine with a serverless VPC network. The region of the GAE is set in northamerica-northeast1 (which can't be changed as described in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations)), so I am trying to set up the VPC connector to be in the same region, following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access).

When creating a new serverless VPC connector, it looks like there is no region selection for northamerica-northeast1, as shown in the screenshot. Is there a way to set up the connector to this region already set by app engine? At this point the last thing I want to do is start an entirely new project just to re-setup app engine and other applications on GCP.

I have seen some responses in the past about [getting whitelisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589246/change-gae-application-location/25590841#25590841) to be given access to specific requests such as this, but again, I do not know how to go about that process either, if that is my best option.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting in touch with a helpful Google support rep, this specific region is indeed not supported by VPC networks. My best (and really only) option was to set up a new project, with a new region and match my VPC network to the new region, and then migrate/copy any datasets and apps I was using from the old project to the new.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the current product limitations,to set a connection between App Engine and Compute Engine please file a feature request in our Public Issue Tracker and we will  implement support for the northamerica-northeast1 region. To do so please refer to link[[1]](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui)

Comment: Than you for the comment, I found out about the product limitations as well recently. I have a new project up and running now, but I'll look into filing a feature request if I need something similar done in the future.